# Finding a point clicked in a grid

Tags: graphics, grid, pseudocode

Given this grid ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz39I.jpg is a trapezium/trapezoid, not a square), how do you find the point clicked by the user? I.e. When the user clicks a point in the grid, it should return the coordinates like A1 or D5.

I am trying to write pseudo code for this and I am stuck. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

EDIT: I am still stuck... Does anyone know of any way to find the height of the grid?

Comment: Do u have the coordinates of end points of each line in the grid??

Comment: Nope. This is all the information I have. No coordinates, but just measurements. I feel like there is very little information. Is there a way to find the height of the trapezium given the heights of the first and last grids (as shown in the picture 35px and 120 px)?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a true perspective projection, you can run the click-point through the inverse projection to find it's X,Z coordinates in the 3D world. That grid has regular spacing and you can use simple math to get the A1,D5,etc.

If it's just something you drew, then you'll have to compare the Y coordinates to the positions of the horizontal lines to figure out which row. Then you'll need to check its position (left/right) relative to the angled lines to get the column - for that, you'll need either coordinates of the end-points, or equations for the lines.

Yet another option is to store an identical image where each "square" is flood-filled with a different color. You then check the color of the pixel where the user clicked but in this alternate image. This method assumes that it's a fixed image and is the least flexible.

Comment: This is not a 3D grid. This is just something that is drawn (2D). This is more for a 2D HTML5 game type. I feel like there is very little information. Is there a way to find the height of the trapezium given the heights of the first and last grids (as shown in the picture 35px and 120 px)?

Comment: I'd go with my 3rd option, make another copy of the image and paint each square a different color in the alternate image. Show people the original and use the alternate to determine which square was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the coordinates of end points of the grid lines then

> **Try using the inside-outside test for each grid line and find the position**

Comment: I don't have the coordinates. I only have measurements of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Since this grid is just a 3D view of a 2D grid plane, there is a projective transform that transforms the coordinates on the grid into coordinates on the 2D plane. To find this transform, it is sufficient to mark 4 different points on the plane (say, the edges), assign them coordinates on the 2D plane and solve the resulting linear equation system.